# Why does this code output a syntax error? (python)

Tags: python

```
from random import randint as random

names = ['Ninja','xXx_leet1337_xXx','robert87','nic0','y2ih8','roxky','Wierdio','a3rt','BeastyBoy','bobby']
active_players = names

deaths = (' shotgunned ', ' sniped ', ' ran over ', ' rifled ')

def findDeath():
    current_death = deaths[random(0,3)

while len(active_players) >= 2:
findDeath()
if current_death = ' sniped ':
    sniper_length = str(random(5,100))+ 'm'
    print(active_players[random(0,9)]+' '+current_death+'from '+sniper_length)
else:
    print(active_players)
```

Output:
  File "..\Playground\", line 11
    while len(active_players) >= 2:
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Why?

Comment: Please note that syntax errors and debugging help are off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to close a statement on the previous line:

```
current_death = deaths[random(0,3)
```

This should be

```
current_death = deaths[random(0,3)]
```

Always check the lines **before** where your syntax error occurs :)